Can I SSH with key and then have a simple password for the sudo user?
So I have a server which I connect to with SSH and a key.
I have disabled SSH password login on my normal user. When I use sudo, it's super annoying to having to copy and paste the complex password every time.
What would the implications of using a very simple password (like "1234" or "odus") be, when password login is disabled entirely, and my user is in the sudo group?

You know about the login command right?

Since remote login is disabled entirely, it should be OK to set a simple password, since login would now require physical access. Only do this if you're confident that having a very simple password will not have other implications that might pose a security risk.
However, I would instead set a "semi-complex" password (7-10 characters, mixed letters and numbers). And instead of using sudo many times consecutively, I would log in as root when I'd need to run multiple root commands. This is normally not advised, but as long as the commands are "trivial" (sudo apt upgrade, etc), this is still what I would do.
You could follow this approach by invoking a root shell with:
sudo -s

Again, use with caution, and never run any complex commands or any command you're not 100% sure about.
